# Room: pass columns Name as parameter in DAO Method

Tags: android, android-room

I m using Room to query a table from my local Android sqlite database.

I've created an abstract class Dao , and wondering if i can pass the **name of columns** as **parameters in method** like this :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT :columnName "
        + " from " + Constant.TABLE_NAME
)
public abstract Maybe<List<SomeEntity>> getResults(String columnName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry, that is not supported. Room only supports what SQLite does, and SQLite does not support parameters for column names, table names, etc.

Comment: So suppose i have a Table schema like this : TABLE "TABLE_NAME" ( `FIELD0` TEXT NOT NULL, `FIELD1` TEXT )
I can't get first columns (FIELD0) elements in a query but using it as param in my DAO ?
i think it s possible ...Room accept param in query , but my question was if i can make selected columns Name  also passed as  parameters !???

Comment: @issamux: "my question was if i can make selected columns Name also passed as parameters !?" -- no, sorry, that is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, @Query don't support it.
But You can use `@RawQuery` to do your stuff.

[@RawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RawQuery)

Documentation says

> RawQuery methods can only be used for read queries. For write queries,
> use RoomDatabase.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase().

Use `RoomDatabase.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase()` for write operations.

Comment: yes ofc RawQuery will do the job, thanks @Bharatesh

Answer (score 0):

Room verifies the SQL queries at compile time, so it has to know the final column name.
But with a little bit more code you might be able to work around that:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT " + Constant.COLUMN_A_NAME
        + " from " + Constant.TABLE_NAME
)
public abstract Maybe<List<SomeEntity>> getResultsFromA();

@Query(value = "SELECT " + Constant.COLUMN_B_NAME
        + " from " + Constant.TABLE_NAME
)
public abstract Maybe<List<SomeEntity>> getResultsFromB();

public Maybe<List<SomeEntity>> getResults(String columnName) {
   switch (columnName) {
     case Constant.COLUMN_A_NAME:
        return getResultsFromA();
     case Constant.COLUMN_B_NAME:
        return getResultsFromB();
     default:
        throw "Invalid Column";
   }
}
```

or use an enum instead of the string.