# How to select a specific column from room database given a specific parameter in room query?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

How can I do the following?

I want to select a specific column in my room query. This column will be specified by as a parameter in the query function.

Imagine my database looks like the following:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| ID | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 1  | 13      | 45      | 77      | 12      |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 2  | 5       | 34      | 67      | 7       |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 3  | 8       | 33      | 69      | 12      |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I would like to be able to specify any of the columns and return the value in the specified column for all rows.

```
@Query("SELECT " + desiredSubcategory + " AS subcategoryValue FROM subcategory_table")
List<Subcategory> getSubcategory(String desiredSubcategory);
```

```
class Subcategory {
      Float subcategoryValue;

      public void setSubcategoryValue(Float subcategoryValue) {
            this.subcategoryValue = subcategoryValue;
      }

}
```

Edit 1:
According to this post: [Room: pass columns Name as parameter in DAO Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48038299/room-pass-columns-name-as-parameter-in-dao-method?rq=1)
this feature is impossible to do. However, this was a year ago.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do that. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48038439/1162154).

Answer (score 1):

You can do with Common Table Expression with CASE's like

```
@Query("WITH parms(c) AS (SELECT :columnName) " +
        "SELECT  COALESCE(" +
        "CASE " +
        "WHEN (SELECT c FROM parms) = 'column1' THEN column1 " +
        "WHEN (SELECT c FROM parms) = 'column2' THEN column2 " +
        "WHEN (SELECT c FROM parms) = 'column3' THEN column3 " +
        "WHEN (SELECT c FROM parms) = 'column4' THEN column4 " +
        "END" +
        ",0) AS subcategoryValue " +
        "FROM subcategory_table" +
        ";")
float[] getSubcategory(String columnName);
```

The Subcategory class not needed and is less efficient, but could use if wanted change `float[] getSubcategory(String columnName);` to `List<Subcategory> getSubcategory(String columnName);`

Answer (score 0):

Normal SQL would simply use

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4 from <TABLE>
```

so probably something like

```
@Query("SELECT " + desiredSubcategory1 + " AS subcategoryValue1 + "," +
desiredSubcategory2 + " AS subcategoryValue2 + "," +
desiredSubcategory3 + " AS subcategoryValue3 + "," +
desiredSubcategory4 + " AS subcategoryValue4 + "," +
"FROM subcategory_table")
List<Subcategory> getSubcategory(String desiredSubcategory);
```

Comment: Right. This is my conceptual understanding of how this should work, but this does not work when using Room.