# How to pass column name as a parameter in room database?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-room

I am using `roomdatabase` and I have a lot of categories to query.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE sweets = 1")
LiveData<List<Item>> getAllSweets();

@Query("SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE drinks = 1")
LiveData<List<Item>> getAllDrinks();
```

So the question is, it is possible to make one universal query and pass column name as parameter?
For example:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE :columnname = drinks AND :columnname = 1")
LiveData<List<Item>> getAllDrinks(String drinks);
```

I know that I refer to the columnName but
If columnName is type `int` it shouldn't be?

```
LiveData<List<Item>> getAllDrinks(int drinks)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer:** You can't do that because SQLite doesn't allow that, [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48038299/room-pass-columns-name-as-parameter-in-dao-method).

**Long Answer:**

**There are a couple of drawbacks in your model:**

1. **Database Design Model:** Not that a good database design in terms of [data normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization); why? You have a column for `sweets`, another for `drinks`, maybe one for `meals`.. More columns, means more data storage, more null-able fields in records, and you need a database method for querying each column separately (like what your question about)
2. **To have a variable column name can be error-prone:** what if you pass in a column that doesn't exist in database.. This is one of the features that `Room` provides to you over abstract `SQL queries` where Room provides you a compile-time errors for wrong column names while normal SQLite raises them at Runtime.

What I encourage you to do:

Create a single column that indicates the type of the food; for efficiency you can create it of type `int`, and map each integer value to a certain type of food:

```
1 >> goes for >> sweats 
2 >> goes for >> drinks
and so on..
```

Now you have a single column (not multiple of them as in your model)
Now you can have a single DAO method accessing any type (which you were asking for)

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE :foodtype = type")
LiveData<List<Item>> getAllDrinks(int type) // add the type
```

Note: Also for readability you can use `Enum`'s for your fields and make Room type conversion.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I have one question. Beacuse reading code in comment is hard to read, I made everything in this: https://bugsdb.com/_en/debug/ea279e097a7dcf9fc9b36faa7eaeb1ad. But I didn't use enums earlier so I have a question. When I save chosen category (sweets or drinks etc.) in my app I am doing it like ```Item.Categories food = Item.Categories.SWEETS; ``` and similar with drinks etc. It is good? Is this a properly way to save selected data (for example sweets) as category sweets using enums?

Comment: @Rivke yes this is good and readable more than using abstract numbers around different classes; you may also have a look at [How to do enum Type Conversion and save them into Room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326789/how-to-save-enum-field-in-the-database-room)

Comment: I have one more question. When I pass item object from one activity to another it gives me null in food_type but name_product and amount read properly. When I pass via intent only food_type it gives error/warning ``` Key TEKSAS expected Parcelable but value was a com.example.project.Item$Food_type.  The default value <null> was returned. ``` If I query room using this --> ``` Item item_get2 = Item_DATABASE.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).item_dao().getItemById(id); ``` it works good. So why I can't pass it via intent directly?

Comment: Additionally in first activity, food_type shows correctly value (**Log.i**) so problem is while passing between activities I think.